# LM35 Issues with incorrent values

Tags: arduino, sensor, temperature

I have been working on my project to detect temperature values using LM35 temperature sensor using an Arduino UNO.  I have used this sensor serval times with no issues. But recently none of my LM35 are functioning properly with all codes I have tried. I am baffled with what has happened with them. My connections are also correct. I have tried to re-wire them but everything is in vain. Can anyone please help me.

[image: the temperature values gradually increase and decrease with one of them]

And for another one of my temperature sensor it gives about 40 to 55 degree Celsius at room temperature of 26 C.

The connections are VCC to 5V, GND to GND and Signal to A0 pin of Arduino.

Codes I have [tried](http://www.instructables.com/id/ARDUINO-TEMPERATURE-SENSOR-LM35/).

Comment: And what do the LM35's say if you connect Signal to a multimeter (DC volts mode) or voltmeter (and the other side of the meter to ground?)

Comment: It works fine when individually used when no other sensors are connected to the controller. The other sensors are color and current sensor. Even if these are connected to same power supply rail, it causes extreme amount of noise. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: The right answer is that you bough a fake LM35! That's quite a usual problem these days, especially if you order LM35 from China. I believe that you've got a simple pnp transistor!

Answer (score 4):

Break your problem into three parts:

1. Check your +5 V DC voltage is correct and is stable.
2. Measure the DC volts output of the sensor and compare it with the expected value using the formula in the datasheets.
3. Use a potentiometer or pair of resistors to generate a voltage into your ADC and see if you get a correct and stable reading.

   - If (1) fails then you need to find out what's wrong with your power supply.
   - If (1) is OK and (2) fails then you have faulty sensors.
   - If (3) fails then you have a faulty Arduino or faulty code.

Report back.

Comment: Yes 1 and 2 are correct, I have also tested on my different Arduino. Same results. I have tested multiple codes and again the same results. One of them was lm35 library!

Comment: float temp;
int tempPin = 0;

void setup() 

{ 

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() 

{ 

temp = analogRead(tempPin); 

temp = temp * 0.48828125; 

Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = "); 

Serial.print(temp); 

Serial.print("*C"); 

Serial.println(); 

//delay(1000); 

}

Comment: Why are you posting code as a comment? It belongs in your question and properly formatted. You also haven't replied to Ecnerwal's comment on your OP.

Comment: Actually, I did not actually know how to insert the code into it.

Comment: Use the `{}` code button.

Answer (score 0):

The lm35 can be a difficult sensor to work with sometimes especially if you require some amount of accuracy. I will highlight some possible problems and the solutions you can use.

The lm35 can be very unstable sometimes especially since it is just 10mv/℃. Make sure you are using the on board regulator on the arduino. but never switched mode supply.

In order to increase the precision of your reading, it is better to include this line

```
analogReference( INTERNAL );
```

in your setup(). The arduino will automatically use the 1.1v reference for your ADC. That will increase your precision and reduce many erroneous readings. Although, if you change the analog reference, you should use this code to get your final value:

```
result1 = map( sensorValue1, 0, 1023, 0, 110 );
```

Another thing you might be willing to try is to reduce the rate at which you call `analogRead` or the rate at which you print your result. This can serve as a way of dampening the "glitches".

There is something I read somewhere about using a metal that conducts heat very well and tie the sensor to it. This can reduce fluctuations due to transient environmental disturbances.

Of course you might just as well consider buying some other better modules like DHT11 or DHT22 these sensors are accurate up to 0.5 degrees with digital values. Libraries and example codes on how to use them are online.

Comment: Yes I have DH11 AND DH22, they are definitely noise resistant. But the issue with these is that the max operating temperature of them is 50 or 80 deg respectively. So I opted for LM35 (+100 deg) which is an utter disappointment. I got the problem, other sensors such as colour sensor and the current are interfering with the mechanism of LM35. As soon as I unplug them it performs properly. I tried DH22, it is good but the max of 80 deg is what made me bog down.